# SwiftUI shape view drawn with path does not fill

Tags: swiftui

A SwiftUI View drawn with Path does not fill like I want it. The stroke is seen the correct way. What I want to achieve, you can see in the attached images.

```
struct HalfCirclesSidesLine: Shape {
    var circleDiameter: CGFloat = 10
    let distanceBetweenCircles: CGFloat = 10
    let cornerDistance: CGFloat = 22

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        // Drawing left side
        path = drawSide(path: path, rect: rect, isLeftSide: true)

        // Drawing right side
        path = drawSide(path: path, rect: rect, isLeftSide: false)

        path = drawCorners(on: path, rect: rect, radius: circleDiameter / 2)
        path = drawHorizontalLines(on: path, rect: rect, cornerDistance: cornerDistance)
        return path
    }

    func drawSide(path: Path, rect: CGRect, isLeftSide: Bool) -> Path {
        var newPath = path
        let lengthY = rect.height
        let circleCount = ((lengthY - cornerDistance * 2) / (circleDiameter + distanceBetweenCircles)).rounded(.towardZero)
        let radius = circleDiameter / 2
        let totalHeightForOneElement = distanceBetweenCircles + circleDiameter

        for i in 0..<Int(circleCount) {
            let th = totalHeightForOneElement * CGFloat(i)
            let xPosition = isLeftSide ? rect.minX : rect.maxX

            newPath.move(to: .init(x: xPosition, y: rect.minY + cornerDistance + th))
            newPath.addLine(to: .init(x: xPosition, y: rect.minY + distanceBetweenCircles + cornerDistance + th))

            let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: rect.minY + distanceBetweenCircles + cornerDistance + radius + th)

            newPath.move(to: .init(x: xPosition, y: rect.minY + distanceBetweenCircles + cornerDistance + radius * 2 + th))
            newPath.addArc(center: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: .degrees(90), endAngle: .degrees(-90), clockwise: isLeftSide)

        }

        newPath.move(to: .init(x: isLeftSide ? rect.minX : rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + cornerDistance + totalHeightForOneElement * circleCount))
        newPath.addLine(to: .init(x: isLeftSide ? rect.minX : rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - cornerDistance))

        if isLeftSide {
            newPath.move(to: .init(x: rect.minX + cornerDistance, y: rect.maxY))
            newPath.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(270), clockwise: true)
        } else {
            newPath.move(to: .init(x: rect.maxX - cornerDistance, y: rect.maxY))
            newPath.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(180), endAngle: .degrees(-90), clockwise: false)
        }
        return newPath
    }

    func drawCorners(on path: Path, rect: CGRect, radius: CGFloat) -> Path {
        var newPath = path

        // bottom left
        newPath.move(to: .init(x: rect.minX + cornerDistance, y: rect.maxY))
        newPath.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(270), clockwise: true)

        // top left
        newPath.move(to: .init(x: rect.minX + cornerDistance, y: rect.minY))
        newPath.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(90), clockwise: false)

        // bottom right
        newPath.move(to: .init(x: rect.maxX - cornerDistance, y: rect.maxY))
        newPath.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(180), endAngle: .degrees(-90), clockwise: false)

        // top right
        newPath.move(to: .init(x: rect.maxX - cornerDistance, y: rect.minY))
        newPath.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(180), endAngle: .degrees(90), clockwise: true)
        return newPath
    }

    func drawHorizontalLines(on path: Path, rect: CGRect, cornerDistance: CGFloat) -> Path {
        var newPath = path
        // Line between top corners
        newPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerDistance, y: rect.minY))
        newPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerDistance, y: rect.minY))

        // Line between bottom corners
        newPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerDistance, y: rect.maxY))
        newPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerDistance, y: rect.maxY))
        return newPath
    }
}


struct DashedCircleLine_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            HalfCirclesSidesLine().fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            HalfCirclesSidesLine()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my current solution looks like, it is from the preview.
The stroke works, but if I fill the shape I get a crocked result:
[image: Stroke works, but if I fill the Shape I get a crocked result.]

This is the version I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: If you want to fill the path, it needs to be one continuous path made up of lines and arcs.  You cannot have moves, because that makes the path disjoint and it won't fill.  So start with an initial move, and then follow that with lines and arcs until you get back to the starting point.  Draw your path in a clockwise direction and finish it with a closeSubPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few observations:

1. You want to stroke this as one path, going up one side and going down the other, inserting the corners at the appropriate spots. For example, this might consist of the lower left corner, the left side (going from bottom to top), the top left corner, the top right corner, the right side (going from top to bottom), the bottom right corner, and then close the path.
2. You don’t want any `move(to:)` in your path. You theoretically can replace those with `line(to:)`, but even that is unnecessary. Just draw all the arcs and it will draw the lines between them for you.
3. You don’t want a `VStack`, but rather a `ZStack`.
4. A very minor point, but after you round how many circles to draw on the sides, you probably want to recalculate the height accordingly if you want them to be centered. There are other ways to solve this, but the idea is that you probably want the circles on the sides to be evenly distributed from the top and bottom edges.

So, you might end up with something like:

```swift
struct HalfCirclesSidesLine: Shape {
    var circleDiameter: CGFloat = 10
    let estimatedDistanceBetweenCircles: CGFloat = 10
    let cornerDistance: CGFloat = 22
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        // bottom left
        path.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(270), clockwise: true)
        
        // Drawing left side
        drawSide(path: &path, rect: rect, isLeftSide: true)
     
        // top left
        path.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(90), endAngle: .degrees(0), clockwise: true)
        
        // top right
        path.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(180), endAngle: .degrees(90), clockwise: true)
        
        // Drawing right side
        drawSide(path: &path, rect: rect, isLeftSide: false)
        
        // bottom right
        path.addArc(center: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY), radius: cornerDistance, startAngle: .degrees(270), endAngle: .degrees(180), clockwise: true)
        
        path.closeSubpath()
        
        return path
    }
    
    private func drawSide(path: inout Path, rect: CGRect, isLeftSide: Bool) {
        //var newPath = path
        let lengthY = rect.height
        let circleCount = ((lengthY - cornerDistance * 2) / (circleDiameter + estimatedDistanceBetweenCircles)).rounded(.towardZero)
        let radius = circleDiameter / 2
        let totalHeightForOneElement = (rect.height - cornerDistance * 2) / circleCount
        
        let startAngle: Angle
        let endAngle: Angle
        let x: CGFloat
        
        if isLeftSide {
            startAngle = .degrees(90)
            endAngle = .degrees(270)
            x = rect.minX
        } else {
            startAngle = .degrees(270)
            endAngle = .degrees(90)
            x = rect.maxX
        }
        
        for i in 0..<Int(circleCount) {
            let y: CGFloat
            if isLeftSide {
                y = rect.maxY - totalHeightForOneElement * (CGFloat(i) + 0.5) - cornerDistance
            } else {
                y = rect.minY + totalHeightForOneElement * (CGFloat(i) + 0.5) + cornerDistance
            }
            let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            
            path.addArc(center: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        }
    }
}
```

And

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HalfCirclesSidesLine().fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
        HalfCirclesSidesLine()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works perfectly! Also thanks for the additional tips!