# Draw an arc without the chord

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to draw a shape similar to this SVG in SwiftUI:

```xml
<svg
   width="256"
   height="256"
   viewBox="0 0 256 256"
   version="1.1"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path
     id="path4"
     style="font-size:12px;fill:#000000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.01mm;stroke-linecap:round"
     d="M 0.00 0 A 128 128 0.00 0 0 128 128 L 0 128 Z" />
</svg>
```

[image: Arc shape in SVG].

I am trying to draw a similar shape in SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ArcPath: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        let startPoint = path.currentPoint!
        let to = CGPoint(x: 128, y: 128)
        let radius = 128.0
        let center = CGPoint(x: 128, y: 0)
        let angle1 = Angle(degrees: 90)
        let angle2 = Angle(degrees: 180)
        path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: angle1, endAngle: angle2, clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 128))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ArcPath()
                .fill(.black)
        }
        .frame(width: 256, height: 256)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image: An arc in SwiftUI]

So, instead of just drawing an arc (curve along the circle perimeter), and then continuing the path, SwiftUI also draws a "chord" back to the beginning of the arc. Moreover, this statement seems to be completely ignored: `path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 128))`.
What am I missing here? How can I draw the arc as a path component the way I want?

Answer (score 2):

I switched your view code to use `stroke` instead and it was interesting.

The `move(to...)` seem to add a line to the Path too.

But this code sorted it...

```
struct ArcPath: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: 128, y: 0),
            radius: 128.0,
            startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90),
            endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180),
            clockwise: false
        )
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 128))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

Using `stroke` your original code produces this...

[image]

With the update it looks like this...

[image]

Comment: So the `path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))` breaks it, but why? And what if I do need to move the path somewhere first?

Comment: @MaksimGayduk I'm not sure why it does it TBH. It was def a surprise to me. I didn't think the `moveTo` should add anything to the path. I'd recommend building the path using `stroke` to begin with so you can see each part of the path being created. That way when you need to move around you can always see what is happening.

Comment: @MaksimGayduk See [SwiftUI shape view drawn with path does not fill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77034116/20386264) for some answers.

Comment: The move isn't adding the line but the arc is.  Your arc is drawing from the lower right to the upper left.  The line gets added from the current point if there is one.  If you had used a relative arc `path.addRelativeArc(center: CGPoint(x: 128, y: 0), radius: 128, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), delta: Angle(degrees: -90))` it would have been fine.

Comment: @vacawama ah! OK, so the actual "pen" is moving to the top left, then has to draw down to the bottom right, to then draw the arc back up to the top left. So, we could have done `move(to: CGPoint(x: 128, y: 128))` and it would have fixed it also?

Comment: @Fogmeister, yes. Moving to the bottom right before adding the arc would fix the issue as well, but it is completely unnecessary as you discovered since the addArc correctly starts the path. If the OP wishes to shift the drawing by moving the starting point, then the relative arc would be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```swift
Color.black
    .frame(width: 256, height: 256)
    .overlay {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .scaleEffect(2.0, anchor: .bottomLeading)
    }
    .clipped()
```

[image: Corner]